# Trying to create Finite-State Machine, can't figure out these syntax errors

Tags: vhdl

So I've been trying to figure out where I went wrong in my VHDL code for my finite state machine however I feel a new, more experienced set of eyes may help. Any help would be welcome.

Here is the code (I've marked the lines where the errors occur):

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY part2 IS
        PORT(clk : in std_logic;
                        w : in std_logic;
                        res : in std_logic;
                        st : out std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
                        z  : out std_logic);
END part2;

ARCHITECTURE behavior of part2 is

        TYPE state_type is (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I);
        signal y_Q, y_D : state_type; --y_Q is present state y_D is next state

        BEGIN

        process(w, y_Q)
        BEGIN
        case y_Q is  -- DIFFERENT STATES
                when A => IF(w ='0') then y_D <= B;
                else y_D <= F;
                end if;

                when B => if(w = '0') then y_D <= C;
                else y_D <= F;
                end if;

                when C => if(w ='0') then y_D <= D;
                else y_D <= F;
                end if;

                when D => if(w = '0') then y_D <= E;
                else y_D <= F;
                end if;

                when E => if(w = '0') then y_D <= E;
                else y_D <= F;
                end if;

                when F => if(w = '1') then y_D <= G;
                else y_D <= B;
                end if;

                when G => if(w = '1') then y_D <= H;
                else y_D <= B;
                end if;

                when H => if(w = '1') then y_D <= I;
                else y_D <= B;
                end if;

                when I => if(w = '1') then y_D <= I;
                else y_D <= B;
                end if;

                end case;
                end process;

                --clk and reset
                Process(Clk, reset)
                begin
                if(reset = '1') then y_Q <= A; --resets fsm

                else if(rising_edge(clk)) then
                y_Q <= y_D; --state change;
                end if

                end process; --LINE 70 !!!!! ERROR 1


                Process(st)-- Determines z
                begin --LINE 74 !!!! ERROR 2

                if(y_Q = A)
                then
                st <= "0000000001";
                end if;

                if(y_Q = B)
                then
                st <= "0000000010";
                end if;

                if(y_Q = C)
                then
                st <= "0000000100";
                end if;

                if(y_Q = D)
                then
                st <= "0000001000";
                end if;

                if(y_Q = E)
                then
                st <= "0000010000";
                end if;

                if(y_Q = F)
                then
                st <= "0001000000";
                end if;

                if(y_Q = G)
                then
                st <= "0010000000";
                end if;

                if(y_Q = H)
                then
                st <= "0100000000";
                end if;

                if(y_Q = I)
                then
                st <= "1000000000";
                end if;


                end process;--LINE 122 !!! ERROR 3



        end Behavior;
```

[image: The errors]

Comment: There's an `else if` in that process that should be `elsif`, both occurrences of `reset` should be `res` and all the string values being assigned to `st` are too long or `st` is too short.

Comment: There's also the following process with only `st` in the sensitivity list. That sensitivity list should consist of `y_q`.

Comment: Maybe you should start with a correct indentation to find matching `end` pairs ... Btw. the error message says everything: missing `;` after `end` in `line 70`...

Comment: Welcome to EE Stack Exchange. You should read a document on VHDL indention guidelines: this code is not really readable... You might be able to fix your own error that way (the guidelines weren't invented for no reason). And it is also good practice to label you `process` statements.

Answer (score 2):

Just before line 70, your 'end if' is missing a semi-colon, should be 'end if;'